# Can't convert 'list' object to str implicitly

Tags: python, random

I've got the following Python code which fails with the error stated in the title. Why does it happen and what can I do to make my code work?

```
endingsArray = ["ing","end","axe","gex","goh"]
student=int(input("Enter Number of Students"))
for i in range(0,len(endingsArray)):
    Name=str(input("Enter first three letters of name"))
    import random
    randomNo = random.randint(0,5)
    username=(Name + endingsArray)
    print(username)
```

Comment: Hello! :) You need to specify which array-element should be chosen .. endingsArray[ randomNo ] should do the job

Comment: `random.randint(0,5)` will give an index which will lead to a subscript out of range error 1 out of every 6 times (on average). You could just use `random.choice()` and bypass indices entirely.

Comment: Also, having `import random` inside the loop really makes no sense. Such imports belong just once at the top of your code. It also makes no sense to not use `student` to control the for-loop. You are simply ignoring that variable in the rest of your code.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know what do your realy want. but i think when you want to get username+ending. you must call that list with index e.g : (sorry i remake ur code )

```
endingsArray = ["ing", "end", "axe", "gex", "goh"]
    student = int(input("Enter Number of Students : "))
    for i in range(0, len(endingsArray)):
        randomNo = random.randint(0, 5)
        Name = str(input("Enter first three letters of name"))
        username = (Name + **endingsArray[i]**)
        print(username)
```

hope this help you